# How do I get my InputMethodService

Tags: android, ime

My application has 2 part .An InputMethodService and a Activity.What I do is click on Button in activity to see all available InputMethods but I cannot see my InputMethod in list.

But after that I can see it from  Settings>>>Language and Keyboard

This is the relevant code

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
List<InputMethodInfo> lst = imeManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();
for (InputMethodInfo info : lst) {
   System.out.println(info.getId() + " " + info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
}
```